# foreach object iteration with propereties which contain '@'

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

Here is dump of `$v` which contains object inside

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[69]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'identifier' => string 'FC7C5117-8FF9-4FF4-86D2-F139EDE6EA74-19726-00011178F6D7A5AC' (length=59)
      'fileext' => string 'pdf' (length=3)
  public 'title' => string 'The PDF File' (length=12)
  public 'summary' => string 'Summary for the pdf file stuff' (length=30)
  public 'tags' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[70]
      public 'tag' => string 'PDFTag' (length=6)
  public 'timeSignature' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[71]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          'upper' => string '4' (length=1)
          'lower' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'key' => string 'C' (length=1)
  public 'transposition' => string 'PDF Trans' (length=9)
  public 'bpm' => string '120' (length=3)
  public 'defaultAudio' => string '57895336-6D03-41B4-954C-91DA3F512185-19726-00011178DFE613C5' (length=59)
```

I do

```
                    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) 
                    {
                        var_dump($k1);
                        var_dump($v1);
                                            }
```

and it begins from `title`

```
title
object(SimpleXMLElement)[74]
  string 'The PDF File' (length=12)
summary
object(SimpleXMLElement)[72]
  string 'Summary for the pdf file stuff' (length=30)
tags
object(SimpleXMLElement)[74]
  public 'tag' => string 'PDFTag' (length=6)
timeSignature
object(SimpleXMLElement)[72]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'upper' => string '4' (length=1)
      'lower' => string '4' (length=1)
key
object(SimpleXMLElement)[74]
  string 'C' (length=1)
transposition
object(SimpleXMLElement)[72]
  string 'PDF Trans' (length=9)
bpm
object(SimpleXMLElement)[74]
  string '120' (length=3)
defaultAudio
object(SimpleXMLElement)[72]
  string '57895336-6D03-41B4-954C-91DA3F512185-19726-00011178DFE613C5' (length=59)
```

what i am missing? Why does it skip `@attributes` ?

Comment: Doesn't iterating `SimpleXMLElement` just loop over the nodes?  I think you'll need to call `->attributes()` on each node to check for attributes (including the root element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it skip `@attributes` ?

Using `foreach` with an *XML element's* `SimpleXMLElement` object simply loops over a collection of *elements* only, not any attributes (exactly which elements are iterated depends on the way the object is accessed; it can be all child elements or child elements with a specific local name).

If you want to `foreach` over the attributes of an element, then use the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes) method like `foreach($v->attributes() as $name => $value)`. This method returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object for the attributes, which can be iterated over.

---

A side note worth mentioning is that `attributes()` is not required if you simply want to access an attribute; the array-style syntax `$v['attribute_name']` can be used.

Comment: +1 I'd forgotten about the fact that `SimpleXMLElement implements ArrayAccess` - which is so far as I can tell completely undocumented. It is bizarre though that it shows as if there is a public property called `@attributes` when you dump it - very misleading, and leads to questions like the one you see here. This is precisely why I just use DOM and have done with it, it's so much less confusing.

Comment: @DaveRandom, `SimpleXMLElement` *doesn't* implement that interface, but it does allow array-style access of attributes. The fact that the array-style access is available is documented, briefly and in passing, on the [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) page.

Comment: So it provides a syntax that can only be achieved by implementing an interface, *without* implementing said interface? *<sound of head exploding>*

Comment: It provides a syntax that can only be achieved *in userland code* by implementing an interface.  Core/extension code is a different beast altogether.  It would probably be nice if `SimpleXMLElement` did explicitly implement `ArrayAccess`.

Comment: And therein lies the my real problem with SimpleXML. It does a whole bunch of stuff that can't be reproduced in userland code. I accept that natives that do stuff that wraps C API calls etc won't all be reproducible in userland code, but all libxml actually does is string manipulation. Very complicated string manipulation, but still just string manipulation, and it should therefore be completely reproducible in userland code, should one so desire.

Comment: That's a fair standpoint to have. Personally, I'm more than happy to have internal code doing things that PHP code cannot. Another example would be comparing `DateTime` instances with the standard operators.

Comment: I have always wished that PHP had a magic method that was called when comparing objects which would return a non-object and that would be used for the comparison, then it would possible to implement that sort of functionality yourself. It has certainly annoyed me on many occasions that there is a `__toString()` but no `__toInt()` or `__toFloat()` etc. And I'm sure it wouldn't be that hard to implement, either. But such is life. Still I shouldn't complain about PHP too much - I've spent the last 2 weeks being forced to work in VBA.

Comment: Having other magic methods for scalar casting has been discussed many times ([1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/object_cast_to_types), [2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_casting_to_scalar)) within the PHP internals folks, with various patches supplied. Having a `Comparable` interface has also been discussed ([3](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/comparable)).  These things may come, eventually.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML is yet another strange inconsistency in PHP, and it is somewhat unique. It is tightly integrated within PHP core and displays a few traits that no other class in PHP, including native classes, display - for example it represents a special case in relation to [converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

I could harp on about the oddities of SimpleXML all day, but to cut to the chase, `@attributes` is actually showing you the result of the [`attributes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method of `SimpleXMLElement`, converted to an array. It is not in fact a property.

I personally prefer to use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for everything DOM-related, because while it is more bloated and long-winded I find it doesn't do things I'm not expecting, which SimpleXML does. This is mostly user error/mental block on my part, but it is coupled with slightly inadequate documentation and a few bits and pieces of nonstandardness - such as the one you have run into here.